# Создание массива из вложенных элементов Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, рекурсия, список, словари

Всем привет!

Помогите пожалуйста разработать алгоритм.

Есть исходный список, состоящий из словарей:

```
[

   {
       'A':'string1',
       'B':'string_5',
       'C':'string_9,
        ...
       'N':'stringN',
       'metric1':5,
       'metric2':7
    },

    {
      'A':'string1',
      'B':'string_5',
      'C':'string_11,...
      'N':'stringN',
      'metric1':10,
      'metric2':45
    },

    {
      'A':'string2',
      'B':'string_7',
      'C':'string_15,
       ...
      'N':'stringN',
      'metric1':234,
      'metric2':78
    },

    .......
 ]
```

На выходе нужно получить такой список:

```
       [

           {
            'A':'string1', 'metric1':sum(all metric1 where 'A'='string1'), 
            'metric2':sum(all metric2 where 'A'='string1'), 
            'B': [

                   {
                  'B':'string_5',
                  'metric1':sum(all metric1 for combination where 'A' in 
                                          'string1' and 'B' in string_5), 
                   'metric2':sum(all metric2 , where combination Similarly 'metric1'), 
                   'C':[

                         {
                           'C':'string_9', 'metric1':sum(all metric_1 for 
                     combination where 'A' in` 'string1' and 'B' in string_5 and 'C' is 'string_9'),
                           'metric2':sum(...)
                          }, 
                          {
                            'C':'string_11',
                            'metric1':sum(...)
                            'metric2':sum(..)
                          }
                       ]

                   }
                 ]
             },
             {
               'A':'string_2', 'metric1':sum(all metric1 where 'A'='string2'),
              'metric2':sum(...), 
              'B': [

                      {
                        'B':'string_7','metric1':sum(all metric1 for   
                  combination where 'A'='string_2' and 'B'='string_7'), 
                        'metric2':'sum(...),
                        'C': [
                               {
                                 'C':'string_15', 
                                  'metric1' :sum(...), 
                                 'metric2':'sum(...)
                               }
                             ]
                       }
                    ]
               },

         ....

            .....
        ]
```

Т.е. алгоритм должен делать следующее:
обходим по порядку весь список словарей, и группируем по первому ключу (в нашем случае "А", суммируя при этом каждую из метрик, и на выходе получая словарь с ключами:
 - Название уровня
 - Сумма каждой из метрик
 -Пустой список, с названием следующего уровня. ("B":[])

Затем проходим по второму уровню ("B"), группируем их по второму ключу, и те элементы, у которых первый уровень "А" - их заносим в созданный ранее массив "B", опять таки суммируя все метрики, и на выходе получая аналогичный словарь как выше, где есть пустой список с название следующего уровня ("С"). И так далее, до последнего уровня.

Пробовал использовать рекурсивную функцию, которая вызывала себя для каждого элемента на нижнем уровне, но в итоге получил словарь, в который входили только первые элементы на каждом из уровней, и не допёр, как сделать рекурсию для каждой полученной ветки в результате группировки.

Comment: А как порядок ключей A,B,C определяется? лексикографически? То есть как узнать, что B должен быть вложен в A, а не наоборот?

Comment: @jfs  А они изначально упорядочены, т.е. именно таков порядок их вложенности.

Comment: порядок ключей в `dict` неопределён (и даже если порядок известен для выбранной версии/реализации Питона, не следует на него полагаться, иначе могут возникнуть скрытые баги, если вашу программу на другой версии/реализации Питона запустить).

Comment: @jfs Понял что не совсем верно ответил  - есть дополнительный список, который как раз содержит порядок ключей. order=['A','B','C']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно простой код получается, если сгруппировать словари по их значению текущего уровня (такого как `'string1'`) и просто суммировать значения соответствующих метрик для выбранных словарей, вызывая функцию рекурсивно, чтобы получить значения для нижних уровней:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import defaultdict

def sum_metrics(dicts, metric_names=('metric1', 'metric2')):
    return {metric: sum(d[metric] for d in dicts) for metric in metric_names}

def generate_level_simple(dicts, levels):
    if not levels: # no levels
        return {}  # nothing to generate

    level, *levels = levels # pop level
    level2dicts = defaultdict(list)  # level value -> dicts
    for d in dicts:
        level2dicts[d[level]].append(d)

    return {level: [{level: level_value,
                     **sum_metrics(level_dicts),
                     **generate_level_simple(level_dicts,  levels)}
                    for level_value, level_dicts in level2dicts.items()]}

print(generate_level_simple(dicts, order)[order[0]])
```

где `dicts`—это исходный список словарей из вопроса, а [`order`—это список, определяющий порядок вложенности уровней](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565177/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-python?noredirect=1#comment738319_565177).

#### Результат

```
[{'A': 'string1',
  'B': [{'B': 'string_5',
         'C': [{'C': 'string_9', 'metric1': 5, 'metric2': 7},
               {'C': 'string_11', 'metric1': 10, 'metric2': 45}],
         'metric1': 15,
         'metric2': 52}],
  'metric1': 15,
  'metric2': 52},
 {'A': 'string2',
  'B': [{'B': 'string_7',
         'C': [{'C': 'string_15', 'metric1': 234, 'metric2': 78}],
         'metric1': 234,
         'metric2': 78}],
  'metric1': 234,
  'metric2': 78}]
```

Код работает, но он может быть неэффективен так как более высокий уровень заново суммирует метрики, уже посчитанные на нижних уровнях. Этого можно избежать небольшим изменением кода:

```
def generate_level(dicts, level, levels):
    level2dicts = defaultdict(list)  # level value -> dicts
    for d in dicts:
        level2dicts[d[level]].append(d)

    if not levels:  # the deepest level
        return {level: [{level: level_value, **sum_metrics(level_dicts)}
                        for level_value, level_dicts in level2dicts.items()]}

    inner_level, *levels = levels  # pop level
    inner_dicts = (generate_level(level_dicts, inner_level, levels)
                   for level_dicts in level2dicts.values())
    return {level: [{level: level_value,
                     **sum_metrics(level_dict[inner_level]),
                     **level_dict}
                    for level_value, level_dict in zip(level2dicts, inner_dicts)]}

level, *nested_levels = order
print(generate_level(dicts, level, nested_levels)[level])
```

В данном случае суммируются метрики для словарей только с непосредственно прилегающего уровня (без ненужного дублирования).
Результат тот же.

Код использует Питон 3 синтаксис для разложения/распаковки списков и словарей, введённый в [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) и [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) (последнее доступно начиная с Python 3.5).

Comment: Вы просто гений, уровень python - Бог !) Спасибо))  @jfs